# How to sort the [include] entitycollection in Ria Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, datagrid, ria

I have datagrid with another datagrid in the rowdetails and I am not able to sort the details view
I have tried the following but no success :(

The main datagrid is populated in the following manner:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    NamskeidinDomConTxt = new Namskeidin_DomainContext();

    this.NamskeidinDomConTxt.Load(this.NamskeidinDomConTxt.GetNamskeidQuery(), LoadBehavior.RefreshCurrent, loadOperation =>
        {
            PagedCollectionView pcView = new PagedCollectionView(loadOperation.Entities);
            pcView.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Heiti", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
            namskeidDataGrid.ItemsSource = pcView;
        }, null);
}
```

The datagrid in the detailsrow of the main datagrid is populated in the following manner:
First I catch the following event and get the details datagrid.

```
private void namskeidsHlutarDataGrid_RowDetailsVisibilityChanged(object sender, DataGridRowDetailsEventArgs e)
        {
            verkefniDataGrid = (e.DetailsElement as FrameworkElement).FindName("VerkefniDataGrid") as DataGrid;
            Verkefni_DomConTxt = new Verkefni_DomainContext();
}
```

and then the this event fiers so I can fill the details datagrid when I have got the id:

```
private void namskeidsHlutarDataGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{

    DataGrid dataGrid = sender as DataGrid;
    var item = dataGrid.SelectedItem;
    if (item != null)
    {
        nHlutaId = ((Entity)item).GetIdentity().ToString();
        Verkefni_DomConTxt.Load(Verkefni_DomConTxt.GetVerkefniQuery().Where(v => v.NamskeidsHluta_ID == nHlutaId),
        LoadBehavior.RefreshCurrent, loadOperation =>
            {
                verkefniDataGrid.ItemsSource = loadOperation.Entities;
            }, null);
    }
}


private void GridName_RowDetailsVisibilityChanged(object sender, DataGridRowDetailsEventArgs e)
{
var dataGrid = (e.DetailsElement as FrameworkElement).FindName("detailsDataGrid") as DataGrid;
PagedCollectionView pcView = new PagedCollectionView(dataGrid.ItemsSource as IEnumerable);
pcView.GroupDescriptions.Clear();
pcView.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Name", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
pcView.Refresh();
}
```

There are actualy three datagrids details/details
Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a new PagedCollectionView but your DataGrid's ItemsSource is still bound to the plain IEnumerable. You'll need to bind the ItemsSource to your PagedCollectionView.

**Updated:** So based on your updated code you should just load the child grid the same way you load the parent grid. So instead of:

```
Verkefni_DomConTxt.Load(Verkefni_DomConTxt.GetVerkefniQuery().Where(v => v.NamskeidsHluta_ID == nHlutaId), LoadBehavior.RefreshCurrent, 
loadOperation => { verkefniDataGrid.ItemsSource = loadOperation.Entities;}, null);
```

You could just create your data view here and set the items source to point to it:

```
Verkefni_DomConTxt.Load(Verkefni_DomConTxt.GetVerkefniQuery().Where(v => v.NamskeidsHluta_ID == nHlutaId), LoadBehavior.RefreshCurrent, 
loadOperation => {
  PagedCollectionView pcView = new PagedCollectionView(loadOperation.Entities);          
  pcView.GroupDescriptions.Clear();          
  pcView.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Name", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
  verkefniDataGrid.ItemsSource = pcView;
  }, null);
```

And then get rid of your other event that tries to create the view.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your reply. I had tried to use PagedCollectionView pcView = dataGrid.ItemsSource as PagedCollectionView but that returned null. Can you recomend a way to acomplish this

Comment: Hard to know where to start since you don't provide a lot of your code. How is the ItemsSource binding setup in the first place?

Comment: Hi Bryant I put some more code in the question hope that helps, thanks